# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Computer Graphics' [first moderator election](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close early. Because the election didn't need to be competitive, we've appointed the sole nominee:

[image: Lyssagal]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!